# How can I add delay between thread groups in Jmeter?

Tags: multithreading, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

There are 7 thread groups in our test plan:

```
Thread group 1
Thread group 2
Thread group 3
Thread group 4
Thread group 5
Thread group 6
Thread group 7
```

When thread group 1 finishes, I need to add a delay before thread group 2 starts. I have thought about adding Startup delay (seconds) in each thread group, or adding a beanshell which contains a Thread.sleep(60); for example. Which is the best approach?

Comment: In the TestPlan settings, select 'Run Thread Groups Consecutively'. Use start up delay for each Thread Group. It is very easy to maintain.

Comment: @vins how can we add a delay time between the threads without using it consecutively. Means I have to run the thread groups paralelly using delayed time of having 10 seconds.First thread group will run and after 10 seconds 2nd thread will start paralelly and same goes with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

We can execute and add a delay between Thread Group without using Timer with the given below steps.

1. Add multiple thread groups with multiple requests
2. On each thread group select "Specify Thread lifetime"
3. Set Duration as 10 seconds and Startup delay as 5 seconds
   [Specify Thread Lifetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry4zn.png)
4. Click on Test Plan and uncheck the option "Run tearDown Thread Groups after the shutdown of main threads
5. Select the option "Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e.One at a time)
   [Test Plan Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDipF.png)
6. Create View Result Tree from Listener under the test plan and Run the Test plan.
   [View Result Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvFXm.png)
7. After Run successfully Check the result from View Result Tree.

If we want to use Constant Timer, it will add a delay between each HTTP Request instead of Thread Group. So, we found a different way to add a delay between Thread Group by adding Duration and Startup delay in each Thready Group. For i.e, every request of thread group 1 will be completed within 10 seconds but will also delay 5 seconds. The same way rest of the Thread group will be executed.

Answer (score -1):

Default behavior of JMeter is executing thread groups in parallel. You can avoid that by checking checkbox "execute thread groups sequentially".

Adding startup delay in a thread group is a good way. You also can achieve it like,

[image]

This way is it is applicable to all threadgroups which are executed sequentially. It will add constant delay between execution. Instead of constant time you can add Uniform random timer also.

Comment: how can we add a delay time between the threads without using it consecutively. Means I have to run the thread groups paralelly using delayed time of having 10 seconds. First thread group will run and after 10 seconds 2nd thread will start paralelly and same goes with the rest.

Comment: Adding a `Constant Timer` to the test plan will add a delay between every request within the thread groups, not a delay between thread groups.